# Labeling points with field value except those with a value of 0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am trying to label spot elevation points. Here is what I currently have:

Label expression:

```
Function FindLabel ( [OBJECTID], [CVC_1_Z], [CVC_2_Z] )
  FindLabel = [OBJECTID] & " ELEV(CVC_07)=" & [CVC_1_Z] & " " & " ELEV(CVC_18)=" & [CVC_2_Z] 
End Function
```

Result:

[image: spot elevations]

How can I only label those points with non-zero Z values?

Comment: love your profile pic

Answer (score 6):

I've used this label expression with success when labeling elevations greater than zero:

> ```
> def FindLabel([yourField]):
>     if [yourField] is not None:
>         if int([yourField]) > 0:
>             return [yourField]
>         else:
>             return None
>     else:
>         return None
> ```
>
> Using Python as the parser and checking the Advanced box.
>
> Replace [yourField] with whatever field you are using to label.

I found this as an answer for a similar question: [Expression labelling in ArcMap: Label only where value is > 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90969/expression-labelling-in-arcmap-label-only-where-value-is-1)

Comment: Welcome to the site mf471.  Although this contains a valuable link, it is preferable to convert this into a stand alone answer.  More details here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 2):

Use the ArcMap **Label Manager** from the **Labeling Toolbar**

Choose the **Label Class** you're working with

Click the **SQL Query button**

**Write a query** to filter out features with an elevation of 0 (the features themselves will display, but the labels for those features will not)